# Yammer deny request programmatically

Tags: c#, yammer

Is there a way to reject pending request programmatically, well i don't see any api for that so any yammer expert our there to help?

From Chrome developer tools I see this is the request send by Yammer UI.

```
https://www.yammer.com/****/join_requests/968249/deny
```

Code we have used:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://www.yammer.com/****/join_requests/968249/deny");
                request.Method = "POST";
                string postData = "userId=" + userId;               
                byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

                // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

                // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
                request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

                request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, yammerToken);

                // Get the request stream.
                Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
                // Write the data to the request stream.
                dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                // Close the Stream object.
                dataStream.Close();

                // Get the response.
                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

Error: 404 not  found, its obv the api is not there so any solution

Please find the image
[image]

Comment: I think you probably need to be a little more specific in your question. Do you have some existing automation integrated with Yammer, or are you just starting from scratch? What is the actual requirement? Is it that you have a large number of pending requests and you want to deny them all as a one-off, or do you need something that rejects requests immediately as they are made? It seems weird that you'd have a Yammer group that you don't want anyone to be able to join!

Comment: Hi Dave, I guess my question is self explanatory where I 'm asking something about programming, there are lot of api's in Yammer like https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json which does the job of getting the messages however my scenario is like I want to reject the invitation request made by the user and there is no api for that, so I want to some way achieve the functionality FYI: I 'm programming in C#

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a supported API for doing this.

Comment: Hi Brian Lyttle, I know there is no api, I 'm asking what's the work around for this, I need some way to achieve this..